# Moving GRUB from HDD to SSD - Dualboot Windows 8.1 + Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, ssd

Recently I acquired an SSD and decided to install Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on it and use my HDD as Data Storage. However, I seem to have installed GRUB onto the HDD and not the SSD, which has not created any problems - both Windows and Ubuntu work just fine - but I would like to move GRUB to the SSD, so that if I need to replace my HDD (clicking...) I will not have to format everything and start over.

I ran bootinfoscript and the result said "Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda". My HDD is dev/sda and my SSD is dev/sdb.

So how can I do that? I need to move it completely so that removing the HDD won't harm the installation.

Also, if you would like me to post anymore information just tell me what to do and I will post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install GRUB to your SSD using the command **sudo grub-install /dev/sdb**.

Comment: And what about the one in HDD? If I format the HDD will there be no problem with booting?

Comment: No problem as you have GRUB on the other drive that has been configured to look at your /boot partition for its boot information. Having GRUB installed on multiple drives is how software RAID works too - you can boot from any drive into the same system, useful for when a drive fails.

Comment: Last question: I installed Windows first then Ubuntu second. Windows seems to have created a tiny partition on the HDD. Is that the Windows bootmanager and if I move grub then format the HDD will the deleted bootmanager create any problems? (And I just did that, it said Installing for i386-pc platform. Isn't that for 32-bit? Mine is 64-bit.)

Comment: The small 100MB partition is the "System Reserved" partition that Windows creates. It's not absolutely necessary for Windows to work, but if it's been created, you should leave it there. The i386 reference from GRUB is simply that it is installing for the Intel processor platform. It's not referring to whether or not it is 32-bit or 64-bit in this instance, it's just that unfortunately the moniker "i386" became associated with 32-bit when in reality it doesn't have much to do with "being 32-bit" at all.