# How can I get tu grub if windows is on ssd and half hdd and ubuntu is on the other half of hdd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

So yesterday I thought about installing Ubuntu on my machine which already had (and has) Windows installed on SSD and I was using 500 GB of the HDD.

I deallocated 250 GB from the HDD and successfully installed Ubuntu on those 250 GB. After a restart I was expecting the grub menu to pop up and ask me what to boot, but it did not, it automatically boots into Windows.

How can I get to the grub menu?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps the same question of https://askubuntu.com/questions/506606/moving-grub-from-hdd-to-ssd-dualboot-windows-8-1-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Newer UEFI or old BIOS system? What brand/model? Some like Acer need special UEFI settings. From one time boot key often f12, do you have Ubuntu boot option? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair